# How can I use the Date() use correctly in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having problem using Date Object, when I try to parse unix-timestamp.

example:

```
//I am receiving json data that contains Unix-Timestamp like 1348514100000

var unixTimestamp = data.timestamp; //1348514100000
var date = new Date(unixTimestamp);
console.log(date.getDay()); // is wrong..
```

and example 2:

```
var unixTimestamp = data.timestamp; //1348514100000
var date = new Date();
date = date.setDate(unixTimestamp);
console.log(date.getDay()); // still wrong..
```

I have tried to parse string-timestamp to convert int with

```
var intUT = parseInt(unixTimestamp);
```

but still not the correct date&time.. I have really no idea what to do. How can I get the correct date and time from this unix timestamp?

Thank you!

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "wrong", as that is exactly how you use the `Date()` object in JavaScript.

Comment: wrong means, the "output" is wrong. it gives wrong/different date and time then I expected

Comment: Well what is it that you expect?  When I pass that number to the `Date()` constructor, I get "Mon Sep 24 2012 14:15:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)", which looks right to me.

Comment: Yes, what u got is correct, but I dont get the same result and don't know why.

Comment: JavaScript interprets the time stamp as being a Universal Time value. It then constructs a Date object reflecting the *local time* of the browser (or wherever you're running the JavaScript). If I were in California, then it would have been "12:15:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)".

Comment: Can you show me how you use it to get the correct date&time in javascript?

Comment: You still haven't explained what you mean by "correct".  All I did was call `new Date(1348514100000)` and I got the right answer. What answer do you get?

Comment: Ahh -- make sure you're passing a **number** and not a string! Try `new Date(+unixTimestamp)` in other words ...

Comment: Yes, thats What I am trying to explain. I am receiving json data and the timestamp is as string I think.

Comment: Well formatting the date is a different problem :-)  JavaScript doesn't have much direct support for date formatting, but you can build that yourself from the various "getter" functions on Date objects (getFullYear(), getDate(), getMonth(), etc). Note that the month is a number from 0 to 11, not 1 to 12!

Comment: Oh! That was the problem. Thank you Pointy. 0-11 was my problem, cuz I was getting different date then I av expected. It should be 09 not 08 but now I understand it. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is completely fine, the only issue might be with incorrect type. Trying this:

```
new Date(+"1348514100000")
```

gives me `Mon Sep 24 2012 21:15:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`, others reported `Mon Sep 24 2012 14:15:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)` and `12:15:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`. According to http://www.epochconverter.com it is `Mon, 24 Sep 2012 19:15:00 GMT`.

Note that all these dates represent **exactly the same point in time**. The time zone difference (and thus different hour) is only due to stupid `Date.toString()` implementation (mistake copied from Java language).

The only portable and built-in way to deal with such dates is to either operate on epoch time (milliseconds) or use `getUTC*()` family of methods:

```
new Date(+"1348514100000").getUTCHours()
```

The code above will **always** return 19 (GMT time), irrespective to browser/OS time zone.